# Cannot install 16.04.1 ubuntu on my system running Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have tried a lot I created a Live USB and I allocated 60 GB for the system.

I have Windows on my C drive but I need to install it on my D drive that is 750 GB but; for some reason when I boot into the installer I get to the point where you would click install **alongside Windows 10** but I'm getting the option **install alongside Windows boot loader** instead of Windows 10.

If I try to continue it doesn't notice the 60 GB that I have unallocated for the system to install.

I am having this issue and I need help.

Comment: Selecting "alongside windows" expect that the windows partition is to be reduced in size to make room for a new Ubuntu partiton.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, Ubuntu will not inject an entry into the Windows Boot Loader to boot either Ubuntu or Windows from there. Rather, by default it will configure a chain-loading process by loading the Windows Boot Loader from Grub2 which is the default Linux boot loader in many distributions.

Without further details it's difficult to say for sure, however try the following:

1. If you have UEFI enable, ensure you're using the 64-bit version of Ubuntu as the 32-bit version is incompatible.
2. Use Rufus [here](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to ensure you're getting a good live USB.
3. Disable UEFI secure boot in your BIOS.  The way to do this may vary depending on the manufacturer.
4. With UEFI, Grub2 will not chain-load to Windows.

If you still can't continue in the installer try look at the partition details under the 'Something else' option to see what partitions and free space are visible. Be careful if modifying anything and ensure you have 'good' backups.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu choose the option **something else**

Click on the 60 GB partition and click the **change** button.

You will get pop-up with some options :

*Partition type*, *Format the partition*, *Size of the partition* and *Mount point*

Choose EXT4 for the partition and if there's no content in the partition you won't need to format it. Last choose "/" as the partition mount point.

I would recommend that you use a different partition for the **HOME** directory. This can be done by *editing* the partition.